# In React-Native-Maps: Can you update a specific Marker without having to re-render all markers?

Tags: google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

I have a map using React-Native-Maps and around 200 markers. Those markers are images and a marker starts rotating whenever it gets tapped (the previous marker stops again when getting inactive)

Due to performance issues with markers that have ***tracksViewChanges*** turned on all the time, I had to reduce the usage of it. Now only the active marker has ***tracksViewChanges*** turned on and all others off.

So when a marker is tapped I reload all the markers with a map-function and just the clicked marker gets the ***tracksViewChanges*** - flag turned on.

This reloading process seems to keep increasing my RAM in the performance monitor and I don't really know why..

So my idea was to only render two markers whenever a marker gets clicked, i.e. the previous and current marker to turn off and on ***tracksViewChanges*** respectively.
Because it seems a bit unnecessary to re-render the remaining 198 markers that do not change anyway...

So my question is: Is it possible to take a specific marker out of the list of markers that was previously rendered and manipulate that one only?

Best regards and many thanks in advance!

Comment: TBH, I haven't even read your question. TL;DR... Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue along with a description of what you are unable to achieve and debugging info.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep track of the markers yourself in an array or an object. That way you can refer to them individually via ID or some a custom property or your choosing, granted that it's unique for each marker.

To update a single marker, use [map.data.forEach()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.forEach) to find your marker on the map using a reference explained above, then use it's [get/set functions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker) to modify it.

Comment: Ah thx Mimo, I will try that! I haven't really considered that because I thought this method will only render the single marker and all others would disappear...